# Auto increment number

Tags: sql

Can you any one tell me how to generate auto number in SQL? I have tried but it shows the following error

> "Incorrect sytnax near AUTO_INCREMENT".

What am I doing wrong?

```
create table auto1
(
    Sno int NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT, 
    fname varchar(50)
)
```

Comment: **What** database system, and which version?? *SQL* is just the *Structured Query Language* - a language used by many database systems, but not a database product... Stuff like this is vendor-specific - so we really need to know what database system you're using....

Comment: @Dems: `AUTO_INCREMENT` has no space in MySQL, the underscore is needed.

Comment: What is missing (if it is for MySQL) is an index on `Sno`. It doesn't have to be defined as `UNIQUE` or `PRIMARY KEY` but you need an index for a column to be `AUTO_INCREMENT` in MySQL.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I assume you are using SQL-Server where the syntax is different compared to other DB engines

```
create table auto1 
(
    Sno int NOT NULL IDENTITY(1,1), 
    fname varchar(50) 
)
```

See [here](http://www.google.de/url?sa=t&rct=j&q=sql%20server%20create%20table%20&source=web&cd=1&ved=0CGkQFjAA&url=http://msdn.microsoft.com/de-de/library/ms174979.aspx&ei=WbzRT4jSO-Ki4gTp64GJAw&usg=AFQjCNGV-BrIZ6jxDD4gZbw6MxxY6WHgUw&cad=rja) for details on table creation.

Comment: The OPs example is closer to MySQL; don't guess unless you're covering several based, and certainly don't guess against evidence present in the question.

Comment: the code of the OP should work on MySQL. See [here](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/example-auto-increment.html). That is why it is probably SQL-Server

Answer (score 0):

please try below one

```
CREATE TABLE test (
sno INT NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT PRIMARY KEY ,
fname VARCHAR( 20 ) NOT NULL
)
```

Comment: Auto_increment can be put with primary key only

Comment: That is not correct. `AUTO_INCREMENT` **can be defined** on a column without being `PRIMARY` or `UNIQUE`.